# Best practice for saving related constants?

Tags: c#, types, lookup

In my game I have a enum (about 200 entrys long) with different `GameEntityType`s.

When the game is saved, only an array of `GameEntityType` is written to the savefile.

To reconstruct the gameworld, and to display various information about the `GameEntityTypes`
I need to have a list of quite a few more extra details (constant values).
This means that each `GameEntityType` has other values associated with it.
These values are accessed very often every frame.
My goal is to have a simple way to get all the extra information out of the GameEntityTypeID (the enum).
For example, when I read a 0x1 out of the savefile, I can simply access the Name and all other
information that is implied with the number/enum from an array like this: "Constants.TextureList[`GameEntityType`]",  Would return the string `"Stone_Texture.DDS"`

Example for additional/associated information of the first enum entry:

Types:
`string`, string, `Flag-Enum: "Visual-Classification"`, `bool`, `bool`
Values:
`"StoneBlock"`, `"Stone_Texture.DDS"`, `0x0102`, `false`, `true`

My first approach to this was to create a static GameEntityTypeInfo class that
had a member like the following for every additional info type:

public static const string[] = {"StoneBlock", ...`[more entrys]`};

Of course this is a terrible solution, because I can't just add GameEntityType's
wherever I want without having to update all other lists too.
I also have to separate logical units into datatype units (which is a problem! because when I decide that I don't need an specific EntityType anymore, I have to go trough more than 6 lists!)

Next, I tried to tackle this problem by making a struct out of these datasets
and adding them to a static array.
But creating a List with the additional info while the constructor (while the game is starting)
still doesn't seem like the best solution.

*Question:* How can I create a fast(Name/Classification lookups will be used every frame at least 5000 times in total) and easy access (preferably with indexers) to these constant values?

A lookup similar to this would be best "Constants.TextureList[`GameEntityType`]"

Comment: What is texturelist? how is this related to your gameentitytypes?

Comment: It is a list where i can lookup what texture an entity uses.
Also there would be a few other lists: One list(or array) for each additional value that is implied by the EntityType.

Clarification of the question:
Think of it exactly like a "lookup only SQL table" that stores all different EntityTypes and the matching values, with the columns being:

GameEntityType(uint); Texture(string); Color(int[3]) ...

This datatable enables me to save only the entitytypes(small save file), and then recreating the gameworld with the combined information of the EntityType and the lookuptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By subclassing:

```
public abstract class Enumeration : IComparable
{
private readonly int _value;
private readonly string _displayName;

protected Enumeration()
{
}

protected Enumeration(int value, string displayName)
{
    _value = value;
    _displayName = displayName;
}

public int Value
{
    get { return _value; }
}

public string DisplayName
{
    get { return _displayName; }
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return DisplayName;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : Enumeration, new()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

    foreach (var info in fields)
    {
        var instance = new T();
        var locatedValue = info.GetValue(instance) as T;

        if (locatedValue != null)
        {
            yield return locatedValue;
        }
    }
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var otherValue = obj as Enumeration;

    if (otherValue == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var typeMatches = GetType().Equals(obj.GetType());
    var valueMatches = _value.Equals(otherValue.Value);

    return typeMatches && valueMatches;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return _value.GetHashCode();
}

public static int AbsoluteDifference(Enumeration firstValue, Enumeration secondValue)
{
    var absoluteDifference = Math.Abs(firstValue.Value - secondValue.Value);
    return absoluteDifference;
}

public static T FromValue<T>(int value) where T : Enumeration, new()
{
    var matchingItem = parse<T, int>(value, "value", item => item.Value == value);
    return matchingItem;
}

public static T FromDisplayName<T>(string displayName) where T : Enumeration, new()
{
    var matchingItem = parse<T, string>(displayName, "display name", item => item.DisplayName == displayName);
    return matchingItem;
}

private static T parse<T, K>(K value, string description, Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : Enumeration, new()
{
    var matchingItem = GetAll<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);

    if (matchingItem == null)
    {
        var message = string.Format("'{0}' is not a valid {1} in {2}", value, description, typeof(T));
        throw new ApplicationException(message);
    }

    return matchingItem;
}

public int CompareTo(object other)
{
    return Value.CompareTo(((Enumeration)other).Value);
}
}
```

An article here: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes.aspx

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand exactly what you're trying to get at but it sounds like what you're looking for is a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` if you're after fast lookups.